# mod_security - PCRE limits exceeded

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-security, pcre

Just about on every request I am getting the following error:

`Rule execution error - PCRE limits exceeded (-8): (null).`

After a bunch of googling the only solutions seem to be

a) Add the following in your httpd.conf

```
SecPcreMatchLimit 150000
SecPcreMatchLimitRecursion 150000
```

b) Add the following to your php.ini

```
pcre.backtrack_limit = 10000000
pcre.recursion_limit = 10000000
```

c) Use a version that was compiled with `-disable-pcre-match-limit` option.

---

I am running the following:

ModSecurity for Apache/2.5.12 (http://www.modsecurity.org/).

Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze8 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8

For ModSec my rules, I am using the OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set Project version (CRS) version 2.2.3 which is the newest as of this posting.

My httpd.conf consists of essentially:

```
<IfModule security2_module>
    SecUploadDir /var/asl/data/suspicious
    SecDataDir /var/asl/data/msa
    SecTmpDir /tmp
    SecAuditLogStorageDir /var/asl/data/audit

    Include modsecurity.d/modsecurity_crs_10_config.conf
    Include modsecurity.d/activated_rules/*.conf

    SecRuleEngine On

    # Debug log
    SecDebugLog /var/log/apache2/modsec_debug.log
    SecDebugLogLevel 3

    # Serial audit log
    SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly
    SecAuditLogRelevantStatus ^5
    SecAuditLogParts ABIFHZ
    SecAuditLogType Serial
    SecAuditLog /var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log

    SecPcreMatchLimit 150000
    SecPcreMatchLimitRecursion 150000

</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_admin_flag pcre.backtrack_limit 10000000
    php_admin_flag pcre.recursion_limit 10000000
</IfModule>
```

Of which inside my `modsecurity.d` directory is just all the default rules CRS has in their install file. I have also set the pcre limits to 150000000 and 100000000000 and more, but to no available.

So in conclusion:

solutions `a` and `b` are not working, and I prefer greatly not to do `c`...as I don't really understand/like compiling.

Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: I have this as well using the latest core rules and mod_security source code that I just downloaded. I'm getting these errors for a Rails app, not PHP.

Answer (score 7):

Holy recursion, Batman!

I claim you have something wrong with your mod_security rules. That kind of recursion seems to be unnecessary and will most likely cause some serious load for your server. Fix the rules and/or Apache config, and don't try to "fix" this problem with arbitrarily large numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Watching this closely as I have exactly the same issue and your config looks similar to mine. I'm a first timer to modsecurity, it's not exactly noob friendly!

Agree with Janne. Only advice I have so far is to remove all the core rules and re-introduce them 1 by 1 to start narrowing the problem down. I'm about to do that now.

Also you should change your rule engine setting to

```
SecRuleEngine DetectionOnly
```

while working through config issues, this will allow you to monitor without enforcing - you don't want to enforce the rules while you're still not sure that they're doing what you want.

Please do post back with your learnings if you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SecPcreMatchLimit 150000
SecPcreMatchLimitRecursion 150000
```

The must be found and changed in mod_security config files on some *nix versions.

Answer (score 0):

Atomicorp (sells a security product with modsecurity built in) recommends 250000 on "modern systems".    https://support.atomicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000188468-Rule-execution-error-PCRE-limits-exceeded-8-null-